# Lumen MySQL `QueryException` Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I am making a Lumen application where a specific database is connected during runtime.

```
// Connect to database based on site ID
Config::set('database.connections.runtime', [
    'driver'     => 'mysql',
    'host'       => $configs['db_host'],
    'port'       => 3306,
    'database'   => $configs['db_dbname'],
    'username'   => $configs['db_username'],
    'password'   => $configs['db_password'],
]);
Config::set('database.default', 'runtime');

# The `echo` below returns an expected value
echo print_r(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName(), true).'<br />';
```

However these codes caused the error:

```
function getAll()
{
    return Testimonial::all();
}
```

return this error:

> (3/3) QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known (SQL: select * from `testimonial`)

I have checked that table testimonials does exist.

I think, I remember vaguely that these codes were once working. Changes I have made was downgrading Lumen 5.6 to 5.5.

I have tried to `php artisan cache:clear` but the error is still persist.

Answer (score 1):

'getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known',
seems that host dns lookup failed, 
try:
 1. ping the host from ur server, check it can be connected and get the host ip
 2. replace host domain with its ip, excute again